# MySQL partition by column value like

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I'm trying to partition my tables and so far PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (column name) ... works. I was wondering if we can partition or sub partition by column value like % statement. So I have a table with phone numbers and I would like to partition them based on the first 4 prefix of the number. 1212% , 9901% ...etc . Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Ucin

Comment: Generated stored column must help.

Comment: hmm, you maybe right. Create a generated always stored column which contains substr of the actual number I want to store and then partition by that column. Nice tip thanks, I'll give it a try